# How I can pick the GitLab Access Token using NextAuth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I want make request to GitLab API to get the client repositories, but I can't get the Access Token after I am logged. I just received this data:
[image: Session data]

Comment: It's saved to the `Account` table in your database. No endpoint serves any tokens on NextAuth.